# Error : Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]' and have to find out season_to_date

Tags: javascript, typescript

Use_Case: there is a filter type which consumes the calendar and find out the month_to_date, week_to_date, quarter_to_date -> I have to create the Season_to_date - which will include two seasons S1-> Q1,Q2 & S2-> Q3,Q4.

```
const FY_Q1: string[] = ['AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT'];
const FY_Q2: string[] = ['NOV', 'DEC', 'JAN'];
const FY_Q3: string[] = ['FEB', 'MAR', 'APR'];
const FY_Q4: string[] = ['MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL'];

//-------Seasons-------------------------

const FY_S1 = [FY_Q1, FY_Q2];

const FY_S2 = [FY_Q3,FY_Q4];


export async function getAggregationsForManagerSales(filter: ManagerSalesFilter, isManager: boolean): Promise<ManagerSalesResponse> {
  let managerSalesResponse: ManagerSalesResponse;
  var aggrSalesChart: ManagerSalesChart[] = [];
  var aggrNetSales = 0;
  var aggrReturns = 0;
  var aggrPreSales = 0;
  var aggrLyNetSales = 0;
  logger.debug("Inside getAggregationsForManagerSales()..." );
  try {
    const filterType = filter.filterType;
    const { dateFrom, dateTo, fiscalMonth,fiscalQuarterStart} = await buildDateRangeFromFilterType(filterType, filter.dateFrom, filter.dateTo, filter.storeId);
    logger.debug("dateFrom: " + dateFrom + ", dateTo: " + dateTo + ", fiscalMonth: " + fiscalMonth);
    const fiscalMap = buildDateRangeFiscalMap(filterType, dateFrom, dateTo, fiscalMonth, fiscalQuarterStart);
    const lyDateFrom = await getLastFiscalDay(dateFrom);
    const lyDateTo = await getLastFiscalDay(dateTo);
    let managerSalesQuery = aggreagatedSalesQueryManagerMetrics({ ...filter, dateFrom, dateTo }, isManager, lyDateFrom, lyDateTo);
    const result: EsResponse = await salesEsClient.search(managerSalesQuery);
    logger.debug("EsResponse: \n" + JSON.stringify(result));


function buildDateRangeFiscalMap(filterType: ManagerMetricsFilterType, dateFrom: string, dateTo: string, fiscalMonth: string, fiscalQuarterStart : string): Map<any, any> {
  logger.debug('Inside buildDateRangeFiscalMap');
  const df = new Date(dateFrom);
  const dt = new Date(dateTo);
  const fiscalMap: Map<any, any> = new Map();
  switch (filterType) {

    case ManagerMetricsFilterType.MONTH_TO_DATE:
      var newDate = new Date(df);
      while (newDate <= dt) {
        fiscalMap.set(newDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10), fiscalMonth);
        var temp = newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        newDate = new Date(temp);
      }
      return fiscalMap;

    case ManagerMetricsFilterType.QUARTER_TO_DATE:
      return fiscalQuarterFunction(dateFrom, dateTo, fiscalMonth);

    //------season-to-date----------------------------

    case ManagerMetricsFilterType.SEASON_TO_DATE:
      return fiscalSeasonFunction(dateFrom, dateTo,fiscalQuarterStart);


    //--------------------------------------------------

    case ManagerMetricsFilterType.YEAR_TO_DATE:
      return fiscalQuarterFunction(dateFrom, dateTo);

    default:
      return fiscalMap;
  }
}

function fiscalQuarterFunction(dateFrom: string, dateTo: string, fiscalMonth?: string): Map<any, any> {
  logger.debug('Inside fiscalQuarterFunction');
  var loopStartDate = new Date(dateFrom);
  const dt = new Date(dateTo);
  var loopEndDate = new Date(dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1));
  const fyQuaterlyMap = new Map();
  const fyQuarterlyList = [FY_Q1, FY_Q2, FY_Q3, FY_Q4];

  QUARTER_LOOP: for (const fyQuarter of fyQuarterlyList) {
    const fyQuarterlyMonths = fiscalMonth ? findFiscalQuarter(fiscalMonth) : findFiscalQuarter(fyQuarter[0]);
    if (fyQuarterlyMonths && fyQuarterlyMonths.length) {
      for (var month = 0; month < 3; month++) {
        const fyMonth = fyQuarterlyMonths[month];
        for (var week = 0; week <= 5; week++) {
          if (month == 0 && week == 4) {
            break;
          } else if (month == 1 && week == 5) {
            break;
          } else if (month == 2 && week == 4) {
            break;
          }
          var day = 1;
          while (loopStartDate < loopEndDate) {
            if (day > 7) {
              break;
            }
            fyQuaterlyMap.set(loopStartDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10), fyMonth);
            var temp = loopStartDate.setDate(loopStartDate.getDate() + 1);
            loopStartDate = new Date(temp);
            day += 1;
          }
          if (loopStartDate > dt) {
            break QUARTER_LOOP;
          }
        }
      }
    } else break QUARTER_LOOP;
  }
  return fyQuaterlyMap;
}

function findFiscalQuarter(fiscalMonth: string): string[] {
  if (FY_Q1.includes(fiscalMonth)) {
    return FY_Q1;
  }
  if (FY_Q2.includes(fiscalMonth)) {
    return FY_Q2;
  }
  if (FY_Q3.includes(fiscalMonth)) {
    return FY_Q3;
  }
  if (FY_Q4.includes(fiscalMonth)) {
    return FY_Q4;
  }
  return [];
}


//-------------new_season_date----------------------------------------------------


function fiscalSeasonFunction(dateFrom: string, dateTo: string, fiscalQuarterStart?: string): Map<any, any> {
  var loopStartDate = new Date(dateFrom);
  const dt = new Date(dateTo);
  var loopEndDate = new Date(dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1));
  const fySeasonMap = new Map();
  const fySeasonList = [FY_S1,FY_S2];

  SEASON_LOOP: for (const fySeason of fySeasonList) {
    const fySeasonQuarters = fiscalQuarterStart ? findFiscalSeason(fiscalQuarterStart) : findFiscalSeason(fySeason[0]);
    if (fySeasonQuarters && fySeasonQuarters.length) {
      for (var quarter = 0; quarter < 2; quarter++) {
        const fyquater = fySeasonQuarters[quarter];
        for (var months = 0; months <= 4; months++) {
          if (quarter == 0 && months == 3) {
            break;
          } else if (quarter == 1 && months == 3 ){
            break;
          }
          var day = 1;
          while (loopStartDate < loopEndDate) {
            if (day > 7) {
              break;
            }
            fySeasonMap.set(loopStartDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10), fyquater);
            var temp = loopStartDate.setDate(loopStartDate.getDate() + 1);
            loopStartDate = new Date(temp);
            day += 1;
          }
          if (loopStartDate > dt) {
            break SEASON_LOOP;
          }
        }
      }
    } else break SEASON_LOOP;
      console.log("---------1--------------", fySeasonMap)
  }
  return fySeasonMap;
}


function findFiscalSeason(fiscalQuarterStart: string): string[] {
  if (FY_S1.includes(fiscalQuarterStart)) {
    return FY_Q1;
  }
  if (FY_S2.includes(fiscalQuarterStart)) {
    return FY_Q2;
  }
  return [];
}
```

Season_to_date is build by me it is not working fine. Kindly let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happened while compiling the findFiscalSeason function with `fySeason[0]` as a first argument here:

```
const fySeasonQuarters = fiscalQuarterStart ? findFiscalSeason(fiscalQuarterStart) : findFiscalSeason(fySeason[0]);
```

`fySeason[0]` has type equals to `string[]`, while 1st argument of findFiscalSeason should has type equals to `string`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've got errors in this bit of your code

```
if (FY_S1.includes(fiscalQuarterStart)) {
 return FY_Q1;
}
if (FY_S2.includes(fiscalQuarterStart)) {
 return FY_Q2;
}
```

`FY_S1` and `FY_S2` are seasons and thus are arrays of arrays, so you can't check directly if they contain strings. You could loop through them to make the check, but this logic doesn't make much sense to me - why is that if the second season includes start of the quarter you return the second quarter (the one that is supposed to be in the first season)? You sure you didn't mean `FY_Q2.includes(fiscalQuarterStart)`?